# A cotton-y connection

Tags: wordplay, pattern, connections-puzzle

The following words and phrases have something in common:

> 1. Final
> 2. In case
> 3. Record
> 4. Defeated
> 5. Desire

Figure out what that connection is, then fill in the blanks with suitable phrases:

> 1. Cotton item
> 2. ???
> 3. Cotton item
> 4. Cotton item
> 5. ???

Comment: While writing this quick puzzle, I discovered that “cotton” can also mean “to begin to understand.” So, I hope you guys can “cotton” on to what is going on here ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first part:

> Final = **LAST**
>  In case = **LEST**
>  Record = **LIST**
>  Defeated = **LOST**
>  Desire = **LUST**

The second part, the best I could come up with:

> Cotton item = **BALL** (cotton ball)
>  Not the Cotton "Belt" = **BELL**
>  Cotton item = **BILL** (dollar bills are made of 75% cotton 25% linen)
>  Cotton item = **BOLL** (cotton boll is the clump of cotton on the plant)
>  Not the Cotton "Bowl" = **BULL**

Comment: Yes, you got the connection and filled in the blanks! The title wasn’t part of the puzzle, but I appreciate your effort to make it work (all I needed was the explanation behind the phrases you chose) EDIT: I changed the title of the puzzle, so you can choose more creative phrases for your answer :)

Comment: @PiIsNot3 I don't have anything more creative at the moment.  If I think of something, I'll edit it in.